# Processing-A shape is selected by either pressing a key ‘1’ or or key ‘2’ so that shape 1 or shape 2 can be picked up respectively

Tags: processing

Draw two shapes on the sketch (e.g. a rectangle and a circle). Use the UP, DOWN, LEFT and RIGHT keys to control the movement of the selected shape. A shape is selected by either pressing a key ‘1’ or or key ‘2’ so that shape 1 or shape 2 can be picked up respectively.I want to select the shape by pressing the key "1" or "2", but they cannot run.`

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int ex= 0;
int ey= 0;
 
void setup(){
  size (400, 400);  
}
 
void draw(){
  background(80);
  rect(x, y, 25,25);
  ellipse(50, 50, 50, 50);
}
 
void keyPresse() {
  if ( (key == '1')) {
    if (keyCode == UP) {
      y -= 10;
    } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
      y += 10;
    } else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
      x -= 10;
    } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      x += 10;
    }  
  } else if ((key == '2')){
      if (keyCode == UP) {
      ey -= 10;
    } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
      ey += 10;
    } else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
      ex -= 10;
    } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      ex += 10;
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you click [edit] under your question and explain a bit more clearly what you mean by "but they cannot run"? How exactly are you testing this code, and what happens - if there's an error message in your browser's console, paste the whole message into your question, as text; if not, describe clearly what you wanted to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: `keyPresse` is a typo. You have just defined some random function which isn't a Processing event handler.

Comment: I'm sorry for not explaining the problem clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo. The name of the key board callback is [`keyPressed`](https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html). However, there are also some logical issues.

---

Crate an array for the `x` and `y` coordinates. And an index variabel (`shape_i`):

```java
int x[] = new int[]{100, 100};
int y[] = new int[]{200, 100};
int shape_i = 0;
```

Draw the shapes on its position. (`x[0]`, `y[0]`) is the position of the rectangle and  (`x[1]`, `y[1]`) is the position of the ellipse:

```java
void draw(){
  background(80);
  rect(x[0], y[0], 25, 25);
  ellipse(x[1], y[1], 50, 50);
}
```

Change the index (`shape_i`) when <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>2</kbd> is pressed. Change (`x[shape_i]`, `y[shape_i]`) when an arrow key is pressed:

```java
void keyPressed() {
  if (key == '1') {
    shape_i = 0;
  } else if (key == '2') {
    shape_i = 1;
  } else if (keyCode == UP) {
    y[shape_i] -= 10;
  } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
    y[shape_i] += 10;
  } else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    x[shape_i] -= 10;
  } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
    x[shape_i] += 10;
  }
}
```

---

Complete example:

```java
int x[] = new int[]{100, 100};
int y[] = new int[]{200, 100};
int shape_i = 0;  
 
void setup(){
  size (400, 400);  
}
 
void draw(){
  background(80);
  rect(x[0], y[0], 25, 25);
  ellipse(x[1], y[1], 50, 50);
}
 
void keyPressed() {
  if (key == '1') {
    shape_i = 0;
  } else if (key == '2') {
    shape_i = 1;
  } else if (keyCode == UP) {
    y[shape_i] -= 10;
  } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
    y[shape_i] += 10;
  } else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    x[shape_i] -= 10;
  } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
    x[shape_i] += 10;
  }
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the logic error. I voted to close the question as soon as I saw the typo, but will retract my vote. +1

Comment: Sorry, I realized that I used the wrong keyPressed. Thank you so much for helping me solve the problem!