# How can I selected shape when I pressed keyboard "1" and "2" in processing

Tags: processing

The question is create two shape and move them, when you pressed '1',you can control square move,when you pressed '2' you can control circle move.
This is what i did so far.
my class

```
class MyShape{
int x,y;
void display(){
stroke(0);
rect(200+x,200+y,50,50);
}
void cycle(){
stroke(0);
ellipse(100+x,100+y,50,50);
}
void move(){
if(keyPressed && key == CODED){
if(keyCode == LEFT){
x--;
}else if(keyCode == RIGHT){
x++;
}else if(keyCode == UP){
y--;
}else if(keyCode == DOWN){
y++;
}
 }
  }
   }
```

main function

```
MyShape obj;

void setup(){
size(400,400);
obj = new MyShape();
}

void draw(){
background(0);
obj.display();
obj.cycle();  
obj.move();


}
```

I try to using if to choose these two shape,but it's doesn't work,i can't see the shape when i running or i can't control it

thanks for you guys help, i'm appreciate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Processing-A shape is selected by either pressing a key ‘1’ or or key ‘2’ so that shape 1 or shape 2 can be picked up respectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66918393/processing-a-shape-is-selected-by-either-pressing-a-key-1-or-or-key-2-so-tha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by separating your circle and your square in two separate classes and then create a super class called "Shape". Then your Circle and Square class will inherit from this Shape class.
Shape class file:

```
abstract class Shape
{
  int x, y;
  
  abstract void display();
  
  void move()
  {
    if(keyPressed)
    {
      if(keyCode == LEFT) x--;
      else if(keyCode == RIGHT) x++;
      else if(keyCode == UP) y--;
      else if(keyCode == DOWN) y++;
    }
  }
}
```

Square class file:

```
class Square extends Shape
{
  void display()
  {
    stroke(0);
    rect(200+x,200+y,50,50);
  }
}
```

Circle class file

```
class Circle extends Shape
{
  void display()
  {
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(100+x,100+y,50,50);
  }
}
```

After that we need to find a way to select which shape to move relative to the key pressed. We can do that by creating a variable that will hold the current shape to move and change it when we press the '1' key or the '2' key. Main file :

```
Circle circle;
Square square;

Shape currentShape;

void keyPressed()
{
  if(key == '1')
    currentShape = square;
  else if(key == '2')
    currentShape = circle;
}

void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  circle = new Circle();
  
  square = new Square();
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  circle.display();
  square.display();
  
  if(currentShape != null)
    currentShape.move();
}
```

Comment: thanks for you help Gabriel Baril, I was stuck for this question for a long time,it's works now, I am appreciate!